# PHP decode UTF-8 in URL ie &title=%C5%8Cyu to Ōyu not ÅŒyu

Tags: php, url, post, utf-8, utf

Please can you help me decode this URL so that it displays properly using PHP to output

This is the link
http://www.megalithic.co.uk/visits.php?op=site&sid=18341&title=Ōyu

I think it's actually coming through as UTF-8 - ie 
&title=%C5%8Cyu

$title displays as ÅŒyu

How do I convert this in PHP? I need to use ISO-8859-1 on the page

None of these work

```
$title=iconv("UTF-8","ISO-8859-1",$title); 
$title=iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $title);
$title = utf8_decode($title);
$title = urldecode($title);
```

Do I need to use the Multibyte MB extension and if so how?
Many thanks in advance
Andy

Comment: that's an output problem. you're dumping $title into a non-utf display. php already urldecodes for you when it builds $_GET, so `echo $_GET['title']` is going to a non-utf environment.

Comment: What is your iconv implementation (look in `phpinfo()`)? `libiconv` should work fine and `glibc` is returning question marks sometimes.

Comment: Thanks: iconv support  enabled
iconv implementation  glibc
iconv library version  2.12

Directive Local Value Master Value
iconv.input_encoding ISO-8859-1 ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding ISO-8859-1 ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding ISO-8859-1 ISO-8859-1

Comment: echo $_GET['title'] outputs: ÅŒyu - thanks

Answer (score 2):

If that link is to your PHP page, and you get the value via `$_GET['title']`, then it's already decoded from the URL encoding and `$_GET['title']` holds a UTF-8 encoded string with the character Ō. This character cannot be encoded in ISO-8859-1. If that is a strict requirement, you'll have to encode the character as HTML entity in order to express it in a strictly ISO-8859-1 encoded page:

```
echo htmlentities('Ō', ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 1):

The character "Ō" is not there in ISO-8859-1, so it is not possible to convert it from UTF-8 with any of the standard charset conversion functions.

It might, however, be possible to write a function that converts to numerical HTML encodings, like `&#x14C;` for "Ō".